# R find values from intervals

Tags: r, vector, any

I have a data frame `x`:

```
   begin end
1     1   3
2     5   6
3    11  18
```

and a vector `v <- c(1,2,5,9,10,11,17,20)`
I'd like to find all values from vector that are elements of any of interval from data frame. So i would like to get a vector `c(1,2,5,11,17)`. How is it possible?

Comment: Are your intervals non-overlapping? See `?findInterval` -- `v[findInterval(v, x$begin) == (findInterval(v, x$end) + 1L)]`

Answer (score 3):

To get row-wise values, use `apply` on `MARGIN` `1` with `intersect`

```
apply(df, 1, function(a) intersect(v, a[1]:a[2]))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2

#[[2]]
#[1] 5

#[[3]]
#[1] 11 17
```

OR `unlist` to get a vector

```
unlist(apply(df, 1, function(a) intersect(v, a[1]:a[2])))
#OR
intersect(v, unlist(apply(df, 1, function(a) a[1]:a[2]))) #as commented by akrun
#[1]  1  2  5 11 17
```

Comment: I think you can call `intersect` one time after `unlist`ing`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` to get the sequence between corresponding, `begin/end` values in a `list`, `unlist` the `list` and use `intersect` to get the elements common in both the `vector`s

```
intersect(unlist(Map(`:`, x$begin, x$end)), v)
#[1]  1  2  5 11 17
```