# Find values in range with intervals from another dataframe

Tags: r, apply

I have the following dataframe :

```
Slope_dist <- structure(list(Position = c(20050.1922349798, 20110.4724044041, 
20191.8668595827, 20209.8075446083, 20244.6752987018, 20263.9822049159, 
20281.782344302, 20339.2211613006, 20358.3354024594, 20370.722420919, 
20395.377680624, 20406.7879210336, 20417.9283092158, 20455.6496718925, 
20479.0385128396, 20501.7426189056, 20530.4426620887, 20545.6276949356, 
20565.6992623778, 20574.9800715668, 20610.1055692376, 20619.5632306316, 
20640.0318042353, 20662.5285163397, 20678.0711049998, 20728.0530369277, 
20748.5311716087, 20781.8985477679, 20803.6915855313, 20843.5870752152, 
20856.6002233689, 20875.2079652532, 20910.2068809406, 20949.0689551351, 
20981.6679060582, 21008.157713608, 21020.722946091, 21027.5392209007, 
21049.0754010302, 21056.2847182789, 21067.5327571377, 21097.666955358, 
21162.3034637529, 21191.2567346839, 21219.0525816359, 21256.2289764283, 
21278.186923832, 21306.3418371635, 21341.1758417514, 21363.7765045663, 
21391.9063718649, 21416.6257227384, 21437.3631066072, 21478.0691066393, 
21557.1945321691, 21591.6708495434, 21623.0301980433, 21642.8162216291, 
21681.1550612078, 21696.8530294464, 21724.1832903713, 21747.0432903716, 
21788.3796514253, 21809.2891319786, 21868.0746849459, 21887.3999422503, 
21910.0198770017, 21924.9852067378, 21933.1070629672, 21941.3762613802, 
21980.3326219515, 22005.7890082493, 22022.1707115589, 22047.3040639166, 
22111.137487523, 22128.357730103, 22150.7265735056, 22182.3415786673, 
22222.5442348189, 22291.9895833921, 22319.1356529009, 22334.0113617197, 
22387.3595371446, 22403.9537462065, 22447.6810829602, 22483.2660759799, 
22499.5733691005, 22562.986115031, 22662.8280304883, 22706.4703696762, 
22746.1556997065, 22819.1457944559, 22855.3635876921, 22875.5352349709, 
22902.0847525942, 22957.7103635773, 22995.47088817, 23024.2577881698, 
23071.4436263233, 23120.6158721895, 23189.914846126, 23253.9403451628, 
23291.6200759017, 23316.8237464788, 23343.0268716544, 23361.805530698, 
23389.1592375935, 23469.0921241963, 23495.6203198318, 23527.4023309109, 
23555.9283859058, 23569.4356966148, 23603.8822126491, 23642.6629095936, 
23692.0106412791, 23721.6780274693, 23743.4512358392, 23792.2500602618, 
23813.2223751524, 23832.138070993, 23856.4622337952, 23888.5725631732, 
23909.7811011237, 23970.9017054337, 24030.1232125532, 24071.1652924189, 
24155.0784363992, 24177.8387987339, 24206.7075445401, 24279.6943089258, 
24329.8853833694, 24348.4544032582, 24407.3576303126, 24507.3576183248, 
24507.8193927279, 24539.4479996886, 24562.1236476452, 24607.0007819671, 
24651.8561709213, 24687.4597376294, 24726.9202762241, 24778.1191428408, 
24822.9463300509, 24837.6159049882, 24865.8966885446, 24894.8089867817, 
24985.8763360338, 25022.823192405, 25046.4303873288, 25075.9323745911, 
25104.3021534783, 25142.0552146053, 25180.1699099201, 25231.6143254237, 
25265.2144513344, 25327.4651093012, 25374.7087312204, 25423.7989489003, 
25459.7845706211, 25477.2022938917, 25507.4944491312, 25529.098483522, 
25578.2738702741, 25629.5230482399, 25675.5917382505, 25723.8997618035, 
25802.8721399765, 25825.1682152334, 25840.6591922599, 25862.736406394, 
25910.5025641846, 25947.1956975952, 25957.0602557708, 25972.1042614838, 
26006.3597356923, 26052.4522648748, 26075.1429618539, 26098.0382679241, 
26147.5712799422, 26194.8762352625, 26224.7903837271, 26230.7410914303, 
26245.5792590584, 26260.6425148609, 26283.0189946789, 26288.8362590115, 
26290.2456082289, 26337.0044329702, 26398.7722034082, 26435.9195916161, 
26475.2002215784, 26497.0154314277, 26564.7884496797, 26600.0297204946, 
26617.7193411334, 26656.3573707274, 26756.3573296103, 26804.7891065701, 
26859.8740020067, 26874.8808241998, 26894.5474627021, 26976.079281626, 
27004.0651363575, 27036.3292699516, 27076.0375836138, 27134.2989698863, 
27183.7511028997, 27235.5770184326, 27291.5363874587, 27367.2585381897, 
27409.9127591985, 27481.4699344184, 27514.421659216, 27526.9417181747, 
27548.9095790087, 27573.5337665845, 27603.7410637982, 27633.3049625952, 
27660.1228345973, 27706.5481306021, 27744.6552746177, 27799.8746939958, 
27827.6225888095, 27874.2148370961, 27901.6869771114, 27941.06873972, 
27973.5290792013, 28005.9351860739, 28047.5284838274, 28093.0262857489, 
28149.5860049868, 28174.0473704508, 28200.1290278019, 28237.4834827982, 
28281.6203440186, 28321.0575997296, 28356.9024247818, 28426.2692680703, 
28474.9777808938, 28528.6183099093, 28590.3399819464, 28653.7276902158, 
28705.3221867647, 28771.6750663051, 28839.0711558144, 28873.7849748113, 
28902.0141085375, 28925.0891671374, 28940.9195817716, 28952.901213479, 
28987.9458574001, 29050.6031909415, 29073.2556000367, 29098.1321273993, 
29127.4532686908, 29169.2282034608, 29191.1407683677, 29217.3646803424, 
29285.796937809, 29327.586437672, 29357.632608671, 29393.7294719452, 
29434.7425412701, 29483.9642003226, 29530.2002269037, 29579.2642684536, 
29626.1077884932, 29671.4084925518, 29715.6786626469, 29736.8842289964, 
29782.6627220325, 29812.1812620199, 29865.3913597505, 29908.2751187006, 
29952.0471912641, 29996.5436697403), z = c(187.2672652, 187.1217986, 
186.2584989, 186.403588, 186.6508103, 186.1383032, 186.4994892, 
186.2069694, 185.9956084, 185.9556591, 185.9100204, 185.8121442, 
186.0992439, 185.3203804, 185.1519947, 185.3086679, 185.3148411, 
185.1913414, 185.6530752, 185.2825302, 185.7228463, 185.6738259, 
185.3304834, 185.0660987, 184.7228407, 185.4344964, 184.6416122, 
184.1629723, 184.2571574, 184.4624959, 184.2010477, 184.0004145, 
184.0525218, 184.4265289, 184.4705446, 184.3783394, 184.3044489, 
184.15325, 184.4127141, 184.5133324, 184.5263175, 183.957203, 
183.706977, 183.2771633, 183.4873022, 183.088936, 183.3463992, 
183.7300011, 183.4872859, 183.823608, 183.4415333, 183.7585836, 
182.7988309, 183.0949012, 182.9659884, 182.583973, 182.0994702, 
181.7819991, 181.8923573, 181.8556343, 182.187243, 182.0536251, 
181.3224562, 181.5510406, 182.0015316, 181.7831548, 181.4691435, 
181.3401155, 181.1825846, 181.330333, 181.6626175, 181.3303651, 
182.0733587, 180.9152915, 180.8800619, 180.9082559, 180.4907946, 
180.3165434, 179.7600379, 180.0166976, 179.729782, 179.7924402, 
179.0597265, 178.8301054, 178.5535377, 178.2356128, 179.1967386, 
178.1608011, 178.0127677, 177.7123829, 177.3844628, 176.9334484, 
176.7644824, 176.5047362, 176.61006, 176.4907622, 176.8821416, 
176.8229425, 176.3284377, 176.0219082, 175.7523202, 175.9124704, 
175.7102376, 175.7158936, 175.5697954, 175.2542928, 175.1539444, 
175.1185139, 175.1008981, 174.8779171, 174.7359684, 174.8817621, 
174.5669114, 174.5000447, 174.3078941, 174.3926073, 174.446785, 
174.0763993, 174.0523021, 173.896748, 174.1993161, 174.1117634, 
173.8716424, 173.4946397, 173.1463487, 173.1424816, 172.984107, 
172.9852339, 172.7504738, 172.9168535, 172.560829, 172.5459307, 
172.1637209, 171.9408003, 171.9658188, 171.9216137, 171.7987355, 
171.3705061, 171.3259284, 171.0473307, 171.1077598, 170.7673053, 
170.7634505, 170.5907732, 171.2716619, 170.6855766, 170.1470021, 
170.1316105, 170.1470357, 170.0249277, 169.9253362, 170.147975, 
170.284323, 170.5674842, 170.4391188, 169.7584658, 169.7809526, 
169.4934415, 169.618645, 169.6235596, 169.7289311, 169.4695897, 
169.2688258, 169.1374755, 169.036443, 168.8268389, 168.9022142, 
168.8125284, 168.6891905, 168.7912245, 168.4287076, 168.239135, 
168.5173184, 168.707585, 168.0277414, 168.0918881, 168.4157468, 
168.0463874, 167.9688345, 167.7476632, 167.8537527, 167.7759124, 
167.5738351, 167.6342952, 167.5422242, 167.7618224, 167.6738667, 
167.7290136, 167.7153277, 167.3791535, 167.4367812, 167.4086957, 
167.0254655, 167.1123887, 166.9821399, 167.049424, 166.9433231, 
166.9865714, 166.7621219, 166.8271848, 166.6075849, 166.4407139, 
166.4646829, 166.479504, 166.1666693, 166.3939654, 165.9928141, 
166.0618503, 165.7432745, 165.3683625, 165.1440958, 164.7407328, 
164.7784055, 164.705625, 164.6796036, 164.8261219, 165.1576709, 
164.95386, 164.1798594, 164.7801228, 164.5181857, 165.0971833, 
164.7017912, 163.8024551, 163.6742467, 163.8085094, 163.7620657, 
163.8424387, 164.0981544, 164.020935, 163.9389082, 163.9135036, 
163.8746567, 163.9396068, 163.4738404, 163.3197032, 163.6309329, 
163.5415696, 164.105021, 163.1213276, 162.9424282, 162.6306208, 
162.4756253, 162.9796422, 164.0585453, 161.8723889, 162.0860369, 
161.8058982, 161.5859566, 161.554536, 161.6882613, 161.3419375, 
161.1156476, 161.3210415, 161.327211, 160.8817779, 161.2530659, 
161.2319792, 161.0300462, 161.3102327, 160.7304839, 160.5633526, 
160.7824178, 160.8492086, 161.0215661, 160.5641769, 160.6587997, 
160.6684475, 160.626968, 160.6266274, 160.3135264, 160.1919477, 
159.7848531, 159.7236499, 159.9490276, 159.7046466)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-276L))
```

And I would like to create list of data with all the observations matching the intervals included in the `GranLoc$class`column (the values from the intervals are coming from `LimAm`and `LimAv`columns).

```
GranLoc <- structure(list(Position = c(24227.2648812785, 24734.298042626, 
23614.5044091602, 23411.6656589101, 23820.6758165764, 28156.8064389983, 
28071.477862813, 25913.3311561408, 26121.5891980586, 26297.4309004006, 
26607.7160671692, 26627.2410903841, 26926.4833867431, 22508.5733691005, 
28021.291958933, 27225.6538904977, 27581.7683084438), ID = c(11, 
12, 24, 7, 9, 3, 2, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 6, 25, 5, 4
), LimAm = c(24202.2648812785, 24709.298042626, 23589.5044091602, 
23386.6656589101, 23795.6758165764, 28131.8064389983, 28046.477862813, 
25888.3311561408, 26096.5891980586, 26272.4309004006, 26582.7160671692, 
26602.2410903841, 26901.4833867431, 22483.5733691005, 27996.291958933, 
27200.6538904977, 27556.7683084438), LimAv = c(24252.2648812785, 
24759.298042626, 23639.5044091602, 23436.6656589101, 23845.6758165764, 
28181.8064389983, 28096.477862813, 25938.3311561408, 26146.5891980586, 
26322.4309004006, 26632.7160671692, 26652.2410903841, 26951.4833867431, 
22533.5733691005, 28046.291958933, 27250.6538904977, 27606.7683084438
), class = structure(c(9L, 11L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 33L, 31L, 13L, 15L, 
17L, 20L, 20L, 23L, 1L, 29L, 25L, 27L), levels = c("(22483.6,22533.6]", 
"(22533.6,23386.7]", "(23386.7,23436.7]", "(23436.7,23589.5]", 
"(23589.5,23639.5]", "(23639.5,23795.7]", "(23795.7,23845.7]", 
"(23845.7,24202.3]", "(24202.3,24252.3]", "(24252.3,24709.3]", 
"(24709.3,24759.3]", "(24759.3,25888.3]", "(25888.3,25938.3]", 
"(25938.3,26096.6]", "(26096.6,26146.6]", "(26146.6,26272.4]", 
"(26272.4,26322.4]", "(26322.4,26582.7]", "(26582.7,26602.2]", 
"(26602.2,26632.7]", "(26632.7,26652.2]", "(26652.2,26901.5]", 
"(26901.5,26951.5]", "(26951.5,27200.7]", "(27200.7,27250.7]", 
"(27250.7,27556.8]", "(27556.8,27606.8]", "(27606.8,27996.3]", 
"(27996.3,28046.3]", "(28046.3,28046.5]", "(28046.5,28096.5]", 
"(28096.5,28131.8]", "(28131.8,28181.8]"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I tried this found in another [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311258/r-find-values-from-intervals) but it didn't worked

```
apply(GranLoc , 1, function(a) intersect(Slope_dist$Position, a[2]:a[3]))
```

Comment: `LimAm` and `LimAv` are columns number #3 and #4 of your data.frame. Why are you using 2 and 3 in your function ? (`a[2]:a[3]`)

Comment: My bad, I have changed the code.

Comment: Sounds like a join? `Slope_dist |> dplyr::inner_join(GranLoc, join_by(Position >= LimAm, Position <= LimAv))`

Comment: Thank you, It was what I needed @JonSpring 
After, I can eventually split them by class to obtain a list (or aggregate the observation by class).